# In C#, how to compare 2 strings, 1 of string had '*' / wildcard

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

How to compare two strings, one of which contains wildcard symbols?
Like this:

```
string string1 = "/api/mymember/get";
# * is any text
string string2 = "/api/*/get";
```

I'd like a way to make `string1` equal `string2`.

In C#, is the function `regex.match` able to do that? If `string2` is a pattern.

Or I need custom a script to compare it?

Comment: VB.NET has that built-in in the form of the *LIKE* operator, that has some wildcards including the asterisks (*). One of the rare cases where you get a true benefit using VB.NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator?redirectedfrom=MSDN
One might wrap it into a lib function in its own assembly available for C# too, if needed often. Or even as an extension method to the string type

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to turn a `*` wildcard into valid `Regex`:

```
string string2 = "/api/*/get";
Regex regex = new Regex($"^{String.Join(".*", string2.Split('*').Select(x => Regex.Escape(x)))}$");
```

That produces `^/api/.*/get$` as the `Regex`. I anchored it to the start and the end of the string to make sure it matched everything.

```
string string1 = "/api/mymember/get";
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(string1));
```

That produces `True` to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

You will also need to import the namespace for regex:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Actual regex code requested:

```cs
string string1 = "/api/mymember/get";

// Regex
string string2regexPattern = "^/api/[^/]+/get$"; // Regex pattern for matching string

// Output
bool doesString1MatchPattern = Regex.IsMatch(string1, string2regexPattern);
```

Comment: @Enigmativity why do you keep removing the resource links!

Comment: @user23655351 learn more here [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) [c sharp conner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-regex-examples/) [byte hide blog](https://www.bytehide.com/blog/regex-csharp)

Comment: Because you need to answer concisely. Links are discouraged unless you are providing specific references supporting what you've already put in the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity the resources are specific to regex in csharp and how to use it, first resource was the official microsoft site, the other 2 was more simple for begginners

Comment: I would suggest that you reference the specific elements of the Regex that you've put in your answer only - not just general links to Regex tutorials. And if you're going to put in links then you should have already put the content in the answer itself. So, that would mean explaining how your Regex works in the answer and then link only to provide references for that explanation. That would be a high quality answer. Just throwing in broad links hoping that someone might read about the technology you've used isn't overly helpful.

Comment: Compromis: Point to Regex, and link to the offical source, as I edited ;)